# Get a single document with many collections from FirebaseFirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream, stream-builder

I am trying to get a stream of a single document that has multiple collections from Firebase Firestore.

data structure:

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "test@email.com": {
                "anger": [
                    {
                        "1": {
                            "answerText": [
                                "answer1",
                                "answer2",
                                "answer3"
                            ],
                            "category": "anger",
                            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "lastModified": "2023-06-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "step": "1",
                            "watchedVideo": false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "2": {
                            "answerText": [
                                "answer1",
                                "answer2",
                                "answer3"
                            ],
                            "category": "anger",
                            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "lastModified": "2023-06-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "step": "2",
                            "watchedVideo": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "anxiety": [
                    {
                        "1": {
                            "answerText": [
                                "answer1",
                                "answer2",
                                "answer3"
                            ],
                            "category": "anxiety",
                            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "lastModified": "2023-06-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "step": "1",
                            "watchedVideo": false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "3": {
                            "answerText": [
                                "answer1",
                                "answer2",
                                "answer3"
                            ],
                            "category": "anxiety",
                            "dateCreated": "2023-05-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "lastModified": "2023-06-05T14:54:49.297",
                            "step": "3",
                            "watchedVideo": false
                        }
                    }
                ]

            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Below is what I currently have working but this is only getting one of the collections for the user.

I want **all of the collections** below the user's email address.

```
Stream<Iterable<AnswerModel>> getAllUserAnswers({
    required UserModel user,
  }) {
    String uid = user.email;
    print('GETTING USER ANSWERS: answers/$uid/');
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('answers').doc(uid).collection('anger')
        .snapshots()
        .map(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs
            .map((doc) => AnswerModel.fromMap(doc.data())).toList()
    );
  }
```

And here is how I am using the method above inside a StreamBuilder.

```
return StreamBuilder(
      stream: answerRepo.getAllUserAnswers(user: userModel),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            userAnswers = snapshot.data as List<AnswerModel>;

            if (userAnswers.isNotEmpty) {
              return ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
                itemCount: userAnswers.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var category = userAnswers[1].category;

                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 20),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        // ...add items to display info from stream
                    ],)
                  );
                },
              ),
            }
          }
      });
```

Comment: A single query cannot work across multiple collections of different names.  You will need one query for each collection.  You can combine two query streams using the information in the duplicate.  Do a google search for "stack overflow flutter query two collections at the same time" to find more options that were not upvoted.